# GridView result appears if click Search

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp-classic

please give me correct way of movemenent. where can i get useful info? 
what i want is: -

there is the form with parameters and 2 buttons: Search, Reset.

i want to implement logic - input some params and click search button - GridView as result is shown  below.

examples, articles would be helpful.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example with mvc3 from www.asp.net/mvc

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: ok, i'll try to specify more next time :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of good tutorial available. Consider reading them.

Main Idea is to filter the data & then bind it to the GridView.

Eg.

```
DataTable data = GetData();
DataView dv = data.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "id= " + 2;
GridView1.DataSource = dv;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Eg.

[Asp.Net GridView Control with Multiple Filters](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/Asp.Net_GridView_Filter.aspx)

[ASP.NET Data Controls](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/aspnet-data-controls)